# Office-js: Insert a new column in Excel and partially fill it with new data

Tags: ms-office, office-js, excel-2016

As excited as I am about [the new Office.js](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office), I seem to struggle to get it to perform even the most basic excel operations and have had extremely limited success finding answers on their api.

Anyways, **how can I insert a new column into excel and partially fill it with data?**

I have something like:

```
Excel.run(async (ctx) => { 
    let sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getRange("C4:C5").insert('right');
    range.values = [["foo"],["bar"]];
    await ctx.sync();   
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

But the problem with this code is that is that it inserts the new data where I want it, to the right of column C, but instead of creating a new column, it just **shifts over the data in all the other columns, but only on rows 4-5** which messes up the rest of my spreadsheet/table.

Instead, I'd like to first, insert a new column to the right of C, and then in that new column, assign it an array of values to partially fill it. Thanks.

---

Edit:
**This is what I'm getting:**

```
 _______________________
|  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
-------------------------
| ... | john| 4   | ... |
| ... | jeff| 87  | ... |
| ... | mary| 9   | ... |
| ... |  foo| cory| 54  |    <--- just shifts data in rows 4 and 5 over
| ... |  bar| eric| 33  |
| ... | paul| 5   | ... |
-------------------------
   ^----------------------------- column I have a reference/address too (column C)
```

**This is what I want:**

```
 _______________________
|  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
-------------------------
| ... |     | john| 4   |   
| ... |     | jeff| 87  |
| ... |     | mary| 9   |
| ... |  foo| cory| 54  |
| ... |  bar| eric| 33  |
| ... |     | paul| 5   |
-------------------------
```

Comment: Could you draw out a picture of what you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a hard time wrapping my head around the Office-js way of doing things, but I was able to get it mostly working with something like:

```
  ...
  sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange("C:C").insert('right'); 
  await ctx.sync();

  let range = sheet.getRange("C4:C7");
  range.values = [["foo"],["bar"]];
  await ctx.sync();
  ...
```

I was originally hoping to add a new column to the right of the column I started with and add data in that new column, but since I don't actually hard code addresses in my code, this turned out to be easier and still operate close enough to what I wanted... but I am definitely still open to a better or more correct way of doing this.

Comment: If you create a drawing of what you want to happen, that would help.  But in any case, you do not need the middle `await ctx.sync()`, you can have both things be part of the same batch.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this, coming from VBA. The trick it took me a while to understand was that an entire column must be passed to `.insert`.

I made a small function which will return the new range relative to the old range and takes an optional column header and you can specify "column header up one".

This is because the range I am giving to the function is a single column in a table, but only the body, not including the header. The returning range is also the body, but the header has been set to one row above the rng.

Example:

```
function Get_InsertCol(rng, opt_colheader, opt_colheaderupone, opt_shiftdir) {
    if (opt_shiftdir == undefined) { opt_shiftdir = 'right' }
    rng.getColumn(0).getEntireColumn().getOffsetRange(0, 1).insert(opt_shiftdir);
    if (opt_colheader != undefined) {
        if (opt_colheaderupone == undefined) {
            rng.getRow(0).getOffsetRange(0, 1).values = opt_colheader
        } else {
            rng.getRow(0).getOffsetRange(-1, 1).values = opt_colheader
        }
    };
    return rng.getOffsetRange(0, 1);
}
```

---

```
export async function helloworld(event) {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            //Start Func
            var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

            ws.getRange("B2").values = "ColumnHeader"
            var rng = ws.getRange("B3:B5")
            rng.values = "testdata"

            var offsetrng = Get_InsertCol(rng,"ColHeader",true)
            offsetrng.select();

            await context.sync();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    event.completed();
}
```

Result:

[image]